# Update Build Controller for C# 6 /.NET 4.6 Applications

Tags: visual-studio-2015, tfsbuild

We're still using TFS 2010 and it can't seem to build anything with new C# 6 syntax. I tried to follow this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31654804/update-build-controller-agents-to-build-c-sharp-6-net-4-6-application) to update the ToolPath property in the process template but it didn't help.

What else can I do? Install VS 2015 on the build server?

**UPDATE**

I realized that in the process template there is more than one "Run MSBuild for Project" place that I had to update the ToolPath property. Actually, the one I updated wasn't the right place. After I update the property at the right place the problem went away.

Also, I don't think VS2015 is needed. Just need to install [Microsoft Build Tools 2015](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48159)

Answer (score 0):

If the error message is about"xx can't find the path."
You should install VS 2015 on your build agent.
Make sure you can build your app on your local developer machine .
The build environment on your build machine should  be the same with your local developer machine.

Comment: Sorry about that , i misunderstood you. What I thought is  that you had  amended the build templates to point to MS Build version 14.0. Yes, there are two parameters including 'ToolPath' and 'Tool version' to set. For detail, you can reference this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31180393/buildactivity-ignores-toolsversion