# Update TFS2010 Build Controller for C# 6

Tags: tfsbuild

I still do not understand how to update TFS 2010 to build C#6?
Can anybody explain what I need to do without buying newer version.

- All places where are written I need to use TfvcTemplate.12.xaml - version 12 is not ment to work with TFS 2010.

Comment: Did you check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32851942/update-build-controller-for-c-sharp-6-net-4-6-applications) ?

Comment: yes, and i tried to follow all posts linking from this post. But still not clear: where and what they are doing