# Microsoft.Net.Compilers package's CSC.exe isn't used for some of the projects within the same solution

Tags: msbuild

Our TFS build server is at version 2012 and I was trying it to compile the C#6 and C#7 code and opt in per project basis. I followed simple steps in [c-sharp-6-0-tfs-builds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28287737/c-sharp-6-0-tfs-builds). Sample solution with a single MVC web project worked just fine. Another solution with multiple project worked as well but I noticed in the logs that one of the projects used `v4.0.30319\Csc.exe` instead of `packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.2.0.0-rc4\build\..\tools\csc.exe`. Another solution (MVC Web) that I would like to move to latest version also worked partially i.e. one project (simple class library) compiled fine while the MVC Web project failed.

I have added some debugging statements to track the MSBuild variables and here are the two sets of output from the two projects withing same solution. Solutions compile just fine locally (in VS2015). The msbuild arguments include `/tv:14.0 /p:GenerateBuildInfoConfigFile=false /p:VisualStudioVersion=14.0`. I have tried various combinations of no argument, only VisualStudioVersion and so on.

This project is a class library and MSBuild uses the compiler within Microsoft.Net.Compilers package

```
DebugWriteVariousVariables:
  BeforeTargets: CoreResGen
  UseSharedCompilation : false
  MSBuildThisFileDirectory : C:\Builds\2\MyApp\Sources\MyApp.ServiceFacade\
  MSBuildToolsVersion : 14.0
  BuildingProject : true
  VisualStudioVersion : 14.0
  VSToolsPath : 
  MSBuildBinPath : C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\amd64
  MSBuildExtensionsPath32 : C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild
  CscToolPath : C:\Builds\2\MyApp\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.2.0.0-rc4\build\..\tools
  CscToolExe : csc.exe
GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute:
Skipping target "GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
CoreCompile:
  C:\Builds\2\MyApp\Sources\MyApp\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.2.0.0-rc4\build\..\tools\csc.exe /noconfig /nowarn:1701,1702 ...
```

This project is MVC Web and MSBuild doesn't use the compiler within Microsoft.Net.Compilers package

```
DebugWriteVariousVariables:
  BeforeTargets: CoreResGen
  UseSharedCompilation : 
  MSBuildThisFileDirectory : C:\Builds\2\MyApp\Sources\MyApp\
  MSBuildToolsVersion : 14.0
  BuildingProject : true
  VisualStudioVersion : 14.0
  VSToolsPath : C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0
  MSBuildBinPath : C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\amd64
  MSBuildExtensionsPath32 : C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild
  CscToolPath : C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\
  CscToolExe : 
GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute:
Skipping target "GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
CoreCompile:
  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Csc.exe /noconfig /nowarn:1701,1702 /nostdlib+ /errorreport:prompt /warn:4 ...
```

I can see that `CscToolPath` is set incorrectly. I have read the content of `Microsoft.Net.Compilers.props` but I an unable to see why this is happening.  I have read the contents of .csproj files and compared those. The only obvious difference in terms of building the projects seems to be following two includes

```
  <Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' != ''" />
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" Condition="false" />
```

I can add more debugging statements if needed. What else could I do to troubleshoot and resolve this?

Comment: Could it be that because of the webapplication targets file for MVC the compiler is directly referenced? How comparable is the buildserver with your working development machine?

Comment: @LeonG Those are identical in my machine and build server. Also none of these seem to do anything with compilation but that is one obvious difference I noticed when I compared the csproj files for the project that works and the project that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

you can forcefull inforce project build definition by

below statement on project file

```
<Project ToolsVersion="14.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">     
<Import Project="..\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.2.4.0\build\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.props" Condition="Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.2.4.0\build\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.props')" />
```