# Why does TeamCity generate both a Visual Studio (.sln) build-step and several .NET CLI (dotnet) build steps?

Tags: visual-studio, teamcity

I'm trying to set up my solution to build using TeamCity 2019. When I enter the URL of my project's Git repository, TeamCity auto-detects 4 build steps:

1. Visual Studio (sln) Targets: rebuild
2. .NET CLI (dotnet) restore
3. .NET CLI (dotnet) build
4. .NET CLI (dotnet) test

I'm confused about step 2/3. Why is .NET CLI restoring and building, when a re-build is already performed? Does this imply that something is unusual with my .sln file?

This solution is a group of Windows desktop C++ projects, if that matters.

The reason I'm so concerned with *why* these build steps are appearing is that the .NET CLI build step is failing with a mysterious error, discussed on both the TeamCity forum and StackOverflow:
https://teamcity-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360007640660-error-MSB4019-The-imported-project-C-Microsoft-Cpp-Default-props-was-not-found-when-building-via-TeamCity

[MSBuild in TeamCity of Visual Studio 2012 solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15419610/msbuild-in-teamcity-of-visual-studio-2012-solution)

I haven't been able to find any good answer for why those build-steps are failing. All of the answers on StackOverflow for that issue are pretty shot-in-the-dark "try this, try that" without a simple explanation of where I went wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is list of Build Runners.

In this case you can ignore step 2,3 and 4.

step 1 (first step : Visual Studio (sln) Targets: rebuild) is enough to rebuild your all projects of one .sln.

Teamcity finds [all project-point 4](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/creating-and-editing-build-configurations.html#CreatingandEditingBuildConfigurations-CreatingNewBuildConfigurationpointingtoGitHub.comrepository) types and display the list with compatible runners, user have to decide which should be compatible with the given project.

Comment: Thanks; it would be helpful to have a bit more detail on exactly how TeamCity auto-detects the build steps. I know this is very nitpicky, but *why* does TeamCity find 2 sets of redundant build-steps? I thought I tried TeamCity a few years ago and the auto-detected build configuration worked with zero modification.

Comment: Solution or project can be compatible with multiple runners like one .sln file can be build with VS studio/dotnet cli or msbuild..etc...user have choice to select that....let me if you want more details.

Comment: Yes, I would appreciate more detail. For example: why don't I see msbuild steps automatically generated, but I do see NET CLI?

Comment: Added more detail to my question.