# How do I install the .NET Framework 4.5 reference libraries on Windows Server 2008 R1?

Tags: windows-server-2008, .net-4.5, asp.net-4.5

I have an application whose deploy process builds the source code on the server I'm deploying to.  My production server is Windows 2k8 (not 2k8 R2).  My app is not compiling as the reference assemblies for .NET Framework 4.5 are not present.

I've tried installing the Windows 8 SDK and the option to install the reference assemblies isn't there.  I've also tried installing Visual Studio Express 2012, which supposedly has the assemblies, but no luck there.  So....

How do I get .NET Framework 4.5 applications to compile on a Windows Server 2k8 R1 machine?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Build ASP.NET 4.5 without Visual Studio on Build Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12944502/build-asp-net-4-5-without-visual-studio-on-build-server)

Answer (score 0):

There are manual instructions to install .NET 4.5 Reference assemblies of Windows Server 2008. Refer to following link:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/hh852363.aspx#rn

Answer (score 0):

I've installed the reference assemblies from:

> The Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.1 Developer Pack for Windows Vista SP2, Windows 7 SP1, Windows 8, Windows 8.1, Windows Server 2008 SP2, Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1, Windows Server 2012 and Windows Server 2012 R2

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2878632/en-us