# Microsoft.WebApplication.targets

Tags: tfs, msbuild, build-server

I have a problem when I check in my server to my build server (using TFS), but for some reason, return me the next error:

```
Exception Message: MSBuild error 1 has ended this build. You can find more specific information about the cause of this error in above messages. (type BuildProcessTerminateException)
Exception Stack Trace:    at System.Activities.Statements.Throw.Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
   at System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)
   at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)
```

Adn as detail:

```
\WcfService4.csproj (92): The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
```

I'm not sure what is the problem or what I can solve it. Someone can help me?

Comment: [Did you install Windows 8 SDK?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12944502/147211)

Comment: @KMoraz I'm using a windows 7 (in my build server) and .Net famework 4.5. Works? But the documentation that you sent me is Windows 8 and framwork 4.5

Comment: @KMoraz You can use the SDK to build applications that target these operating systems: Windows 8, Windows 7, Windows Vista, Windows Server 2012, Windows Server 2008 R2, Windows Server 2008. 
I'll try it, thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your reference to

> C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets"

This works if the build is done on a machine that has Visual studio installed on it.
If you change the reference to use nuget instead-
https://www.nuget.org/packages/MSBuild.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.targets/
this package is the equivalent one to your local file. In your csproj.

```
 <Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" />
```

to (for example)

```
<Import Project="$(Yourpackageslocation)\MSBuild.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.targets\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" />
```

You'll need to edit your csproj to point to the Nuget packages file.

Comment: Hi, I tried this solution and it works fine at first, however Visual Studio keeps adding an extra line to the csproj file:
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v16.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" />
this happens when opening the project with different versions of Visual Studio. Has anyone had this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Your application is build on using MSBuild. MSBuild depends on target files that describe how certain application types need to be build.

In this case you are building a web application and your project file contains a link to the `Microsoft.WebApplication.targets` file. This file is installed on your local pc by installing Visual Studio but it's not available on your build server.

You have two options:

- Copy the target file from your local pc to the build server in the correct location
- Install Visual Studio on your build machine

To be honest, the second option is the easiest. You will probably need to copy a lot of files if you want to manually setup your build server. Installing Visual Studio takes care of all dependencies.

Comment: The second is easier.  But I do the harder one.  (and manually copy the files over). Microsoft drives me nuts with this.  The build-machine should not need Visual Studio.  Msbuild.exe and an SDK should be enough, but they don't seem interested in plugging the gaps.

Comment: @granadaCoder The official licensing whitepaper allows you to install VS on the build machine. I see no reason for not doing it.

Comment: All that's needed is the nuget package in your project, this also associates the reference with the code. You shouldn't install more than is required on a build machine.

Answer (score 0):

Either install visual studio on your build machine or copy the targets file from your local machine to the build server