# how to install visual studio 2012 on a windows server 2008?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012, msbuild

I am getting the following error with my build machine

```
C:\Builds\1\Test MVC 4 Application\Build Development - MVC 4 Test App\Sources\Project\TestMVC4\MvcApplication1\MvcApplication1\MvcApplication1.csproj(300,3): error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
```

I understand the error, and know that the issue is that my windows 2008 server only has visual studio 2010... when I try to install installing the Web Tools 2012.2, or even visual studio 2012 it says the server needs to be upgraded or updated to the latest service pack.  I have patched the server to SP2 (latest sp) and all updates.

The only thing I can think of is just to copy those folders from my client machine...

any thoughts?

Comment: Install Windows SDK and try this solution - http://stackoverflow.com/a/19351747/968003

Answer (score 0):

It is not required to install the visual studio on your build server. Checkout the following link

[Build ASP.NET 4.5 without Visual Studio on Build Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12944502/build-asp-net-4-5-without-visual-studio-on-build-server)

If you don't even want to manually copy them to your server, you can also try the following nuget package which suppose to do achieve the same result, but I haven't tried this yet

https://www.nuget.org/packages/MSBuild.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.targets/