# Build and Test the ASP.NET Website and Libraries without having Visual Studio

Tags: msbuild, continuous-integration, mstest, devops, build-server

I am a newbie in the DevOps world, and I would like to set up a CI server.

I have a Continuous Integration pipeline setup (with GO-CD pipelines) on my laptop. I am trying to move it to the server.

On the server, I do not have Visual Studio Tools so the existing MSBuild fails. Is there any way I can run the same pipeline on the server.

I have 2 projects in my MSBuild file.

1. Asp.Net website
2. MS Test Project

Regards,
Kritul

Comment: If anyone looking into this here is another thread that I found. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12944502/build-asp-net-4-5-without-visual-studio-on-build-server

Comment: And this one was for running MSTests on the server. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402899/can-i-use-mstest-exe-without-installing-visual-studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Build ASP.NET code on the Build Server without installing VS**

[Build ASP.NET 4.5 without Visual Studio on Build Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12944502/build-asp-net-4-5-without-visual-studio-on-build-server)

**Using MS Tests on Build Server without installing VS**

[Can I use mstest.exe without installing Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402899/can-i-use-mstest-exe-without-installing-visual-studio)